# VFP Grid + SQL server 2008 - grid not showing correctly

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, visual-foxpro

i am having a problem, i have a grid called "gridbasica" with and i do this:

```
Thisform.GridBase.RecordSource = "sgviemp"
```

sgviemp is a cursor made by executing a select to a SQLserver with the command SQLEXEC.

when i want to modify a registry, i go to another form and do the the update there. so, when i come back to the form with the grid, that grid isnt a grid anymore, is a big white rectangle.

Reading around someone said: delete the recordsource and asingt it again.

```
Thisform.GridBase.RecordSource = ""
*--i do my sqlexe here
Thisform.GridBase.RecordSource = "sgviemp"
```

I do that and it works, BUT, when i click the button modify again the cursos is updated but the modify form doesnt load the fields as it did the first time.

Could anyone help me out with that?

thanks in advance.

--------------- EDIT ------------------

i have been doing this as recommended:

```
lnselect = select(0)
n = SQLEXEC(thisform.conexion,"select emp_ccodigo as Codigo, emp_cnombre as 'Nombre o Razon Social', emp_cnumrif as 'R.I.F'  from sgviempr","sgviemp1")


SET ECHO on
SUSPEND

SELECT sgviemp
ZAP IN sgviemp
*-- browse  *--zaps correctly
*-- SELECT sgviemp1  
*-- browse             *-- sgviemp1  full
APPEND FROM dbf( 'sgviemp1' )
USE IN sgviemp1
*-- BROWSE *--shows sgviemp1 empty

*-- SELECT sgviemp
*-- browse *--shows sgviemp empty too
```

and it doesnt load anything in the grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ever destroy and recreate the cursor a grid is based on. Instead, use "Safe Select," where you create the cursor ahead of time and when you need to repopulate it, you ZAP it and APPEND the new data:

[http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~GridSafeSelect~Wiki](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki%7EGridSafeSelect%7EWiki)

Tamar

Answer (score 0):

Error found here:

```
n = SQLEXEC(thisform.conexion,"select emp_ccodigo as Codigo, emp_cnombre as 'Nombre o Razon Social', emp_cnumrif as 'R.I.F'  from sgviempr","sgviemp1")
```

In the query, the grid sources are named emp_ccodigo ,emp_cnombre and emp_cnumrif  NOT codigo, Nombre o Razon Social, or R.I.F, so needed to do remove the "as" statements. So it looks like this:

```
n = SQLEXEC(thisform.conexion,"select emp_ccodigo, emp_cnombre, emp_cnumrif from sgviempr","sgviemp1")
```